# <tree-ish>:path/to/file で指定されるようなファイルの SHA-1 hash を取得するには？

Tags: git

特定のブランチなど(tree-ish なオブジェクト)に存在する、特定のファイルの SHA-1 ハッシュを取得したいと考えています。

git の原理的に、checkout などによって index や worktree に対して変更を加えずとも、これを実現する方法はありそうだと考えているのですが、ご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

例えば:

```
git THECOMMAND HEAD:hoge-dir/fuga-file
git THECOMMAND origin/develop:README
```

などで、該当するファイルの SHA-1 ハッシュを取得できたらよいと考えています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

確かに Git は SHA-1 ハッシュでオブジェクトを識別していますが、これはあくまでオブジェクトのハッシュであり、ファイルなどのデータ本体のハッシュではありません。

具体的には、データ本体の前にオブジェクトの種類や長さを付加したものが Git におけるオブジェクトであり、これをハッシュ関数にかけたものがオブジェクトIDになっています。

- [Git の仕組み (1) - こせきの技術日記](http://koseki.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/22/inside-git-1#3)
- [Git - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) （もしくは[日本語訳](http://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/ja/v2/Git%E3%81%AE%E5%86%85%E5%81%B4-Git%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88#%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8)）

・・・とここまで書いて、「計算済みのハッシュ値を取り出したい」とは書かれていないことに気づきました。

```
git show origin/develop:README
```

で当該オブジェクトの中身を表示できるので、これを sha1sum にでも流して

```
git show origin/develop:README | sha1sum
```

という感じでどうでしょうか。

ちなみにファイルパスを `./` から始めると、相対パスとして扱われるようです。

Comment: 質問のするときには、計算済みハッシュとファイルの生ハッシュが違うことに気づいていませんでした。この質問を行った目的は、異なるリビジョンにあるファイルの同一性を比較することでした。示したいただいた方法で実現できそうなので accept します。